# iTextSharp 5 - Upgrading SHA1 signing to SHA256

Tags: c#, itext, signing

I am currently having an issue with converting our PDF signing from SHA1 hashing to SHA256. 
We use the Digest signing approach and not signing the entire PDF.

I have gone through a number of articles and have got to the point where the digest comes back in SHA256, however this invalidates the signature (which was previously valid). 
The validity error message is "The document has been altered or corrupted since the Signature was applied" [image: Signature Properties Image]

I am new to Digital Signatures, and as a result would appreciate any assistance in this regard. If any of my terminology is incorrect, please feel free to correct me.

```cs
public static byte[] Sign(PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance, IExternalSignature externalSignature, ICollection<X509Certificate> chain, ICollection<ICrlClient> crlList, IOcspClient ocspClient, ITSAClient tsaClient, int estimatedSize, CryptoStandard sigtype, PdfDictionary customSignatureProperties)
{
    byte[] signedCMS = null;
    List<X509Certificate> certificateChain = new List<X509Certificate>(chain);
    ICollection<byte[]> crlBytes = BuildCrlBytes(certificateChain, crlList);

    if (estimatedSize == 0)
    {
        estimatedSize = CalculateEstimatedSizeOfSignature(crlBytes, ocspClient, tsaClient);
    }

    signatureAppearance.CryptoDictionary = CreateCryptoDictionary(signatureAppearance, customSignatureProperties, PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
    signatureAppearance.PreClose(SignGetEstimatedSizeDictionary(estimatedSize));

    using (Stream data = signatureAppearance.GetRangeStream())
    {
        byte[] documentHash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, externalSignature.GetHashAlgorithm());
        signedCMS = externalSignature.Sign(documentHash);
        byte[] encodedSignatureWithTimestamp = SignAddTimestampToSignedCms(tsaClient, signedCMS);

        if (SignCheckEstimatedSize(encodedSignatureWithTimestamp, estimatedSize))
        {
            byte[] paddedSignature = new byte[estimatedSize];
            Array.Copy(encodedSignatureWithTimestamp, 0, paddedSignature, 0, encodedSignatureWithTimestamp.Length);

            signatureAppearance.Close(SignGetDigestDictionary(paddedSignature));
        }
    }
    return signedCMS;
}
```

```cs
private static PdfDictionary CreateCryptoDictionary(PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance, PdfDictionary customSignatureProperties, PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter)
{
    PdfSignature dictionary = new PdfSignature(filter, subFilter);
    dictionary.Reason = signatureAppearance.Reason;
    dictionary.Location = signatureAppearance.Location;
    dictionary.Contact = signatureAppearance.Contact;
    dictionary.Date = new PdfDate(signatureAppearance.SignDate);
    if (customSignatureProperties != null)
    {
        dictionary.PutAll(customSignatureProperties);
    }

    return dictionary;
}
```

```cs
private static byte[] SignAddTimestampToSignedCms(ITSAClient tsaClient, byte[] signedCms)
{
    ArrayList newSigners = new ArrayList();
    CmsSignedData cmsSignedData = new CmsSignedData(signedCms);
    foreach (SignerInformation information in cmsSignedData.GetSignerInfos().GetSigners())
    {
        byte[] signedDigest = information.GetSignature();
        byte[] timestampImprint = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(tsaClient.GetMessageDigest(), signedDigest);
        byte[] timestampToken = tsaClient.GetTimeStampToken(timestampImprint);

        newSigners.Add(SignerInformation.ReplaceUnsignedAttributes(information, GenerateUnsignedAttributes(Constants.TIMESTAMP_OID, timestampToken)));
    }

    return CmsSignedData.ReplaceSigners(cmsSignedData, new SignerInformationStore(newSigners)).GetEncoded();
}
```

> Edit: Adding in the code implemented by the IExternalSignature Sign method implementation

```
public static byte[] SignDigest(string signer, byte[] digest)
{
  SignatureData data = ConfigurationHelpers.GetSignatureData(signer);
  var cryptoServiceProvider = RSACryptoServiceProvider)data.SigningCertificate.PrivateKey;    // verify private key access
  var contentInfo = new ContentInfo(digest);
  var signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo);
  var cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(data.SigningCertificate);
  cmsSigner.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.WholeChain;
  signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);
  //  Encode the CMS/PKCS #7 message.
  return signedCms.Encode();
}
```

Comment: Where exactly did you try to change the hashing algorithm here?

Comment: In the Sign method. Both the filter and subfilter were previously  PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1. The `externalSignature.Sign(documentHash)`  code was aso updated to return a SHA256 signed cms byte array

Comment: There are more differences between `ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1` and `ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED` than the used hashing algorithm. It looks like the CMS Signature container in your case is created by the `IExternalSignature` implementation you feed into `Sign`. Thus, that implementation must be changed more than only in its hashing algorithm. But it looks weird anyways that the `IExternalSignature` implementation returns a CMS container: That interface originally is meant to return a plain (PKCS#1) signed digest, not a full-blown CMS signature container. That's what `IExternalSignatureContainer` was meant for.

Comment: @mkl, I have added in the implementation for `IExternalSignature.Sign`. Do you have any idea as to what I can do to rectify this issue I am running into, or do you require more information?

Comment: `new SignedCms(contentInfo)` embeds the given data as signed data into the signature container. This is `ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1` style, a SHA1 hash is embedded in the signature container as data. `ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED` is different, though, here the signed data are detached, not embedded. Furthermore, the signed data of the signature container are the actual document bytes, not a hash of them (even though internally, a hash will usually be stored as signed attribute). To detach you can simply use a different `SignedCms` constructor but I don't know how to sign pre-hashed data using the Microsoft APIs.

Comment: I think it might have been initially created to return a CMS container as we use HSM in our ExternalSignature implementation.